# Which to use: self or super?

Tags: python, oop

I am wrapping up a python class deque to queue to make my code more readable:

```
from collections import deque

class Queue(deque):
    def enqueue(self,a):
        super(Queue, self).append(a)

    def dequeue(self,a):
        super(Queue, self).popleft(a)
```

My question is which one I should use here, self.append() or super(Queue, self).append(), Why?

Comment: Why don't you try it? One is clearly the correct answer.

Comment: super points to the parent class, but the self points to this class. you cannot compare those keywords

Comment: I tried to use it but it's fine in both case so I want to know if there is any difference between them.

Comment: Both options are possible - as long as you know the right syntax. Your usage of super makes no sense....read the super() documentation.

Comment: exactly both the options are possible. have you tried before posting?

Comment: @SànLuthra  I did test it. I know both is okay but I am thinking which one is better

Comment: Why not use the builtin Queue class?

Answer (score 2):

`super()` is used to call a base class method that is redefined in the derived class. If your class were defining `append()` and `popleft()` methods extending their behavior, it would be reasonable to use `super()` inside `append()` and `popleft()`. However, your example redefines nothing from `deque`, so there is no need for `super()`.

The following example shows when `super()` is used:

```
class Queue(deque):
    def append(self, a):
        # Now you explicitly call a method from base class
        # Otherwise you will make a recursive call
        super(Queue, self).append(a)
        print "Append!!!"
```

However, in case of multiple inheritance what `super()` does is more complicated than just allowing to call a method from base class. Detailed understanding requires understanding MRO (method resolution order). As a result, even in the example above it is usually better to write:

```
class Queue(deque):
    def append(self, a):
        # Now you explicitly call a method from base class
        # Otherwise you will make a recursive call
        deque.append(self, a)
        print "Append!!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given these two choices, you should use `self.append`, because your code using `super` is not valid Python.

The correct alternate version would be `super(Queue, self).append`.

Comment: Is there any difference on these two methods?

Answer (score 1):

Go for `self` (putting aside that your use of `super` is incorrect as Borealid stated).

However, I believe that in this case it's better to **not** extend `deque`, but rather wrap it.

```
from collections import deque

class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = deque

    def enqueue(self, a):
        return self.q.append(a)

    def dequeue(self, a):
        return self.q.popleft(a)
```

Also, note the returns - in your code they are missing and you cannot get the dequeued value.

Comment: It's usually better to use composition (my example), rather than inheritance (your example). It's much more simple. Also, in your case the details (read: methods) or deque will leak to your class and the abstraction won't be as nice.

Comment: Generally saying composition is better than inheritance?

Comment: @dorafmon: most of the time, yes.

Comment: May I ask why is this? Sorry I am a beginner and not very good at OOP

Comment: This would take a book to explain :). Luckily, there's one verrrrrry goooood: [Code Complete](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735619670/?tag=stackoverfl08-20). Also, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindness and patience.

Comment: @dorafmon: Whether to subclass a type or not isn't always clear-cut. This is illustrated by the classic [circle-ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) encountered when using object-oriented programming.

Comment: Composition is better if your class is just trying to reuse another class' functionality. If a base class really is a more general case of the derived one, inheritance is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Who told you it was a good idea to even think of using `super` instead of `self`?
You want to affect a single instance of the Queue, not append a to the module scope (never mind the fact that super.append throws `AttributeError`)

```
from collections import deque

class Queue(deque):
    def enqueue(self, a):
        self.append(a)

    def dequeue(self, a):
        self.popleft(a)
```